# Greenfoot Counter minus one

Tags: java, greenfoot

Hi i'm trying to decrease the counter with 1 in the public void minScore

score++ adds the counter with 1
what is the equivalent to decrease the counter with 1 ?

```
public class Counter  extends Actor
{
    private int score = 0;

    public void act()
    {
        setImage(new GreenfootImage("Score : 0" + score, 24, Color.WHITE, Color.BLUE));
    }

    /**
     * Increase the total amount displayed on the counter, by a given amount.
     */
    public void addScore()
    {
        score++;
    }

    public void minScore()
    {
        score++;
    }

}
```

Comment: that came to my mind too but that gives a syntax error . it's --score;

Comment: @RemiMinnebo, why? Show your stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `score--` (*return old value and decrease this value*) or `--score` (*decrease this value and return updated value*) to decrease your counter.

I advice you to write methods that returns value, like:

```
public int decrementAndGet() {
    return --score;
}

public int getAndDecrement() {
    return score--;
}
```

By analogy with names of methods in [atomic classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html).